# Identifying common element in list in python

Tags: python

I have two lists. I need to compare elements whether any element in the list is matching or not.
Input:

```
a = ['1001,1715']
b = ['1009,1715']
```

Output : `1715`

Please suggest how to do it? 
I tried doing:

```
set(''.join(a))
```

and

```
set(''.join(b))
```

but it gave me `{'5', '0', '7', ',', '1'}`. how can I convert `['1001,1715']` to `[1001,1715]` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 parts to your problem.

**Convert strings to sets of integers**

Since your string is the only element of a list, you can use list indexing and `str.split` with `map`:

```
a_set = set(map(int, a[0].split(',')))
b_set = set(map(int, b[0].split(',')))
```

**Calculate the intersection of 2 sets**

```
res = a_set & b_set
# alternatively, a_set.intersection(b_set)

print(res)

{1715}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['1001,1715']
b = ['1009,1715']

def fun(a):
  return a[0].split(",")

def intersect(a, b):
  return list(set(a) & set(b))

print(intersect(fun(a),fun(b)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use set intersection:

```
set(a[0].split(',')).intersection(set(b[0].split(',')))
```

Which returns:

```
{'1715'}
```

Converting from `'1001,1715'` to `['1001', '1715']` can simply be done with `.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

A more general solution if you have lists with more elements (e.g `a = ['1001,1715','1009,2000']` )

```
a = [x for xs in a for x in xs.split(',')]
b = [x for xs in b for x in xs.split(',')]
common = set(a).intersection(set(b))
```

Example:

```
a = ['1001,1715','1009,2000']
b = ['1009,1715']
```

Output:

```
{'1009', '1715'}
```